# Cannot run Hive metastore with remote mode

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore

I added Hive in my Apache Hadoop distributed cluster. Instead creating metastore in local directory, I would like to create metastore in HDFS. However, my settings in hive-site.xml don't seem to work. I got the error like below, which seemed that hive still tried to use run metastore in local mode.

> java.sql.SQLException: Directory /home/zz/metastore_db cannot be created.

Can anyone tell me what has gone wrong with my settings? Thanks a lot!

Below is my hive-site.xml content:

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://client2/metastore</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
    <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>hadoop</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.server2.servermode</name>
    <value>thrift</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>master1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://client2:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
```

Comment: You cannot keep your metastore in hdfs, it should kept in databases like mysql, postgres etc.

Comment: I have created a metastore database in mysql, and given all the privileges to my hive user. I also have confirmed that my hive user could log in mysql shell.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `hive-site.xml` file is there in hive classpath. In your case the updated hive-site.xml file is not taking properly instead it takes default values. For explicitly setting hive conf directory following environment variable can be used, before executing hive command

```
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=<PATH-TO-CONF-DIR>
```

(directory contains hive-site.xml should be specified )

For configuring remote mysql as hive metastore, First you got to create the database with enough privileges in remote mysql(metastore database). Initially the database will be empty, So by setting the following property to true will automatically create the metastore schema in the remote db, if the database is empty

```
<property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

If the issue still persists start hive using the option `--config` as follows

```
hive --config <PATH-TO-CONF-DIR>
```

Comment: sachinjose, thank you for your help. Per your suggestion, I set the HIVE_CONF_DIR variable in $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-env.sh file, and changed the value for datanucleus.autoCreateSchema to true.  After restarting hive, I still saw the same error message. Anything else could go wrong? I also found that hive was trying to create metastore_db (instead of metastore) under the directory where I started hive. This is not what I expected, I would like to have the metastore being created at a dedicated place.

Comment: sachinjose, I tried using "hive --config /usr/local/hive-0.11.0/conf" to start hive. Hive did start, but the same error still appeared when I tried "show tables" command at the hive prompt. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like <configuration> tag is missing in your hive-site.xml try adding that

Comment: It's not missing. I just didn't include it in this post. Thanks!